# How do I make a bibtex style file compatible with natbib author citations

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm trying to convert my manuscript to PloS Comp Bio style. They provide a [BibTeX style file](http://www.plosgenetics.org/static/plos2009.bst). This works fine for inline citations with `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` (i.e. `\citep{FooYear}` -> [1]).

However, this style file does not seem to be compatible with the natbib `\citet` command. Whenever I use this I get `\citet{FooYear}` -> "(author?) [1]" (the reference to the author's name is unresolved). What I want is to display a reference to the author (i.e. "Foo & Smith [1]". Obviously, I could fix this manually, but I have quite a large number of cases in the manuscript.

If I use a different BibTeX style then the citations work fine but then the bibliography is not formatted correctly.

### Minimum example

As suggested below here is a minimum example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
   author = {Test, A. and Foo, B.},
   year = {2001},
   title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A02,
   author = {Alex, A. and Bar, B.},
   year = {2005},
   title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

% These citations will work but in the apalike bibstyle they will not be sorted
% in citation order (the first citation is [2]).
\citep{A01}, \citep{A02}, \citet{A02} 

% The author name will be undefined with the unsrt bibtex style
\citeauthor{A02}, \citet{A01}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I ended up solving this by switching to biblatex [see this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52498/plos-comp-bio-biblatex-style)

Answer (score 7):

You observe:

> However, [the plos.bst] style file does not seem to be compatible with the natbib `\citet` command.

You may be mixing up two aspects of the process of creating (i) a bibliography and (ii)  citations to entries in the bibliography. The first aspect -- determining how entries are typeset in the bibliography -- is handled by the bibliography style file (plos.bst in your case). The second aspect -- how citations/references to entries in the bibliography are formatted -- is handled by `natbib`.

By loading `natbib` with the `numbers` option, you are actually instructing the package to create *numeric-style citations*. If you want authoryear-style citations -- as would seem to be indicated by your attempted use of the `\citet` command -- you *must* specify the `authoryear` option instead.

Incidentally, when natbib is set to perform authoryear-style citations, specifying the option `sort&compress` is not necessary (and has no effect).

**Addendum**: From the OP's follow-up comments, I gather that a hybrid between "pure" numeric and authoryear citation styles -- viz., a combination of the author's (or authors') name and the associated citation number -- is what's needed. If this interpretation is correct, the following command may be of use (to be placed in the preamble):

```
\newcommand{\hybridcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \citenum{#1}}
```

Invoking `\hybridcite{People}` (assuming that `People` is the key to an entry which is listed first in the references and which has two authors, named Author1 and Author 2) will then generate the citation `Author1 and Author2 [1]`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear [I'll try and edit the question to make this clearer]. I want my citation format according to the plos2009.bst style file. I also want numeric-style citation so that citep{Test} is transformed into something like "[1]". However, I also want to be able to use \citet when I'm discussing a paper directly (i.e "\citet{People} did some amazing work on ..." which should become "Author1 & Author2 [3] did some amazing work on ..."

Comment: This works fine when using a different bibtex style that is not designed for authoryear citations. However, in this case the bibliography is not formatted correctly (in particular, it is not ordered by citation order).

Comment: Please see the addendum I've provided. I now understand that you're looking for a hybrid citation command that lists both the authors and the number of a given reference. To simplify this task, I suggest in the addendum that you use a new command, say `\hybridcite`, that combines the outputs of `\citeauthor` and `\citenum`.

Comment: Thanks for your continuing help @Mico. That is exactly what I want to do. However, \citeauthor is also undefined with this bibtex style file (so \citenum{Test} -> "1" but \citeauthor{Test} -> "(author?)"). I think the issue is that bibtex styles which are made for numerical citation don't seem to include the author info.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the issue. `\citeauthor` and `\citenum` are commands that are defined in the `natbib` package, independently of the bibliography style file in use. Please consider posting a MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problems you're encountering.

Comment: The commands are defined but the author info does not seem to be included. As suggested, I've edited the question to provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 7 months since the question was brought up, but as I came up with the very same problem I'd like to share with anyone looking for a solution what I found out when dealing with the same.

If we look into `natbib.sty` we will find:

```
 % With standard numerical .bst files, only numerical citations are
 % possible. With an author-year .bst file, both numerical and
 % author-year citations are possible.
```

Pretty much self-explanatory. So, after trying to edit the original .bst file, which is quite easy for minor retouch but impractical for bigger issues, I ended up generating my own .bst file.

On any terminal just execute `latex makebst` and answer the questions prompted. Make sure to choose `Author-year with some non-standard interface` instead of `Numerical as in standard LaTeX` when asked for `STYLE OF CITATIONS`. Basically, the executable will ask you question about how you want you References to look like, more information at [CTAN/custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)