# PLoS Comp Bio Biblatex style

Tags: biblatex

PLoS Comp Bio, I think similar to the other members of the PLoS family, has a simple citation/bibliography style. Citations are numbered [1], and the bibliography is formatted with little punctuation and no italics.

> 1. Fine P, Clarkson J (1986) Individual versus public priorities in the determination of optimal vaccination policies. Am J Epidemiol 124:
>      1012–1020.

They provide a [bst style file](http://www.plosone.org/static/plos.bst) but I'm trying to use `biblatex` because it supports `\citet` commands in numbered citation formats. I've tried hacking away at `biblatex` commands to get the right formatting but I'm struggling. If anyone knows of a `biblatex` style file for PloS (or similar) I'd be most interested.

Comment: If you're planning on submitting a ms. to them, wouldn't it be best to stick with the bibtex style file they provide? I had a paper published in PloS Comp Bio last fall, and the process was painless using their LaTeX/BibTeX templates. Why complicate things? Or do you just happen to like the citation style, and are looking to use it for your own projects?

Comment: @PaulM I'm trying to use biblatex because it solves [a problem with the \citet command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52418/how-do-i-make-a-bibtex-style-file-compatible-with-natbib-author-citations). With their template I can't use the \citet when I want to discuss other author's work - something that I've ended up doing quite a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `biblatex` instead of the journal's `bst`-based style probably isn't a good idea. That said none of the standard or contributed `biblatex` styles will give you this output. The document below demonstrates how you can obtain a custom style based on standard variants of `numeric` and `authoryear`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=none,
            firstinits,terseinits,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% Name list format
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifbibliography{\addcomma\space}{\addspace\&\space}}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% No quotes or italics in titles
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,
                    thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Remove page prefixes
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% Only print journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}}

% Use colon for volume-pages delimiter
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\space}{\addcomma\space}}

% Add labelnumbers to bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

% Omit authoryear disambiguation
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{extrayear}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{glashow,
  author = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title = {Partial symmetries of weak interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl~Phys},
  volume = {22},
  date = {1961},
  pages = {579--588}}
@article{weinberg,
  author = {Weinberg, Steven},
  title = {A model of leptons},
  journaltitle = {Phys~Rev~Lett},
  volume = {19},
  date = {1967},
  pages = {1264--1266}}
@book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading MA},
  date = {1994},
  pagetotal = {528}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{weinberg,glashow,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- The default `\revsdnamepunct` corresponds to the comma printed between the last and first parts in a reversed name. It was introduced in 2.2. For older `biblatex` versions refer to [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17593/4483) from lockstep.
- You can format titles to sentence case. Refer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22980/4483) for details.
- Journal title abbreviations might be better handled using the `string` entry type. Refer to the `bib` file in the `biblatex` documentation for some examples.

Comment: That's fantastic. Thanks so much for your help @Audrey. I tried hacking away at biblatex myself but I was really struggling to get there. Your answer has pointed me on my way.