# Move date after journal name and add semi-colon in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I would like to move the date after the journal name and add a subsequent semi-colon in a biblatex bibliography.

Here is `example.bib`

```
@article{Bopper:2019aa,
    abstract = {},
    author = {Bopper, Big},
    date-added = {2024-01-18 21:26:11 -0800},
    date-modified = {2024-01-18 21:26:11 -0800},
    doi = {111.222.3333},
    journal = {Lace Studies},
    journal-full = {Lace Studies},
    mesh = {},
    month = {Jan},
    number = {D1},
    pages = {55-77},
    pmc = {1234},
    pmid = {555},
    pst = {ppublish},
    title = {Chantilly Lace},
    volume = {4},
    year = {2021},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://doi.org/111/lacey/1234}
}
```

And here is a (reasonably?) MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
defernumbers=true, 
style=numeric, 
bibstyle=authoryear,
date=year, 
uniquelist=false,
uniquename=false,
sorting=none,
giveninits,
terseinits,
dashed=false
]
{biblatex}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428190/how-to-properly-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style-v
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52498/plos-comp-bio-biblatex-style
% Name list format
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifbibliography{\addcomma\space}{\addspace\&\space}}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

It is a funny world \autocite{Bopper:2019aa}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Big bopper bibliographic output]

I would like the bibliography entry to display the date "2021" after the journal name "Lace Studies", place a period after the journal name, and in addition place a semi-colon and space between the newly positioned date and the volume entry "4.D1", thus: "Lace Studies. 2021; 4.D1".

Comment: With `bibstyle=authoryear,` you explicitly request a style that puts the year directly after the authors in the bibliography. Is that intended? What do you want to happen for other entry types?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @moewe. To be honest, this particular journal has such a strange hodgepodge of entry types. For example books: "Bates B. Bargaining for life: A social history of tuberculosis. 1st ed. Philadelphia: University of Pennsylvania Press; 1992.", Book chapters: "Hansen B. New York City epidemics and history for the public. In: Harden VA, Risse GB, editors. AIDS and the historian. Bethesda: National Institutes of Health; 1991. pp. 21-28." Etc. I may just give up and use the Journal's .bst file, though was hoping to understand biblatex better (which is a losing battle for me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the style you want I wouldn't go for `bibstyle=authoryear,` as that moves the year to after the name. If we remove `bibstyle=authoryear,`, we only need to modify the bibmacros `issue+date` and `journal+issuetitle` to remove the parentheses around the year and move the year and volume around, respectively.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  defernumbers=true,
  date=year,
  uniquelist=false,
  uniquename=false,
  giveninits,
  terseinits,
]{biblatex}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52498/plos-comp-bio-biblatex-style
% Name list format
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addperiod\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bopper:2019aa,
  author = {Bopper, Big},
  doi = {111.222.3333},
  journal = {Lace Studies},
  journal-full = {Lace Studies},
  month = {Jan},
  number = {D1},
  pages = {55-77},
  pmc = {1234},
  pmid = {555},
  pst = {ppublish},
  title = {Chantilly Lace},
  volume = {4},
  year = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
It is a funny world \autocite{Bopper:2019aa}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bopper B “Chantilly Lace”. In: Lace Studies. 2021; 4.D1, pp. 55–77. doi: 111.222.3333.]